# How to make alternate table rows colored in collapsible table?

Tags: jquery, html, css

UPDATED THE HTML: 
I have made my HTML table collapsible using a plugin which gives the rows that do not have any other parents as `data-parent=""`. Here I am only showing the parent rows and not their children in the following HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Week1</th>
        <th>Week2</th>
        <th>Week3</th>
        <th>Week4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-parent=""> //should be grey
        <td>+John</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hunohn</td>//ignore
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent="">//white
        <td>+Boney</td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent=""> //grey
        <td>Dwihn</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent="">//white
        <td>+Arkon</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>70</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tyulor</td>//ignore
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to give alternate row colors to only the rows that have `data-parent=""` irrespective of the data that it has. The data rows are sortable. Even after sorting rows with `data-parent=""` should have alternate row colors.

Comment: is there any particular reason you're using the attribute `data-parent` and not just putting a class on the row (like `class="parent"`)

Comment: `data-parent` is an attribute that the collapsible plugin uses to decide what row is the parent row and what are its children. If data-parent="", it does not have any parents and it might have its own children. These children will have data-parent as the id of its parent. eg data-parent="1". want to sort rows that are only parent rows

Comment: see my final edit in my answer, added the `data-parent=''` in the css rule

Comment: @philr check updated html in the question. Might explain what I wanted a bit more. code you provided didn't work as expected

Comment: just remove the css rule for odd and change the color to gray or whatever color you want? https://jsfiddle.net/x6r8rq6a/7/ maybe i'm just not understanding the problem

Comment: @philr https://jsfiddle.net/x6r8rq6a/8/ this is how the code snippet performs. basically only if any tr has data-parent="", give them any rowcolor(grey), for next tr with data-parent="" give it another color (yellow), ignore rows where data-parentis anythin other than "". Would jquery be helpful in this case?

Comment: Check my answer below..

Comment: @blecaf just ran your code in fiddle, doesn't work correctly EDIT: the `~` is definitely the way to go though, gg

Comment: @philr it works the way the question was asked. how does is not run correctly?

Comment: @blecaf yeah i couldn't edit my comment any further but you're right. i upvoted your answer it's the right way to do it

Comment: @philr Thanks :). wanted to be sure.

Comment: @blecaf if i understand the question correctly, they only want to target the one with the empty `data-parent` so just need to change your rule to `[data-parent='']` to make it the perfect answer

Comment: @philr "I want to give alternate row colors to only the rows that have data-parent="" irrespective of the data that it has".  This is what i followed. if it is [data-parent=' '] it will only target empty data-parent and if it contains data if wouldn't find this. that was why in my sample i filled mine with different datas

Answer (score 1):

use the `tr:nth-child(even)` and `tr:nth-child(odd)` selectors

FINAL EDIT: made it work with the data-parent attribute being empty

https://jsfiddle.net/x6r8rq6a/4/

Comment: You beat me to it by 30 seconds. :)

Comment: *"I want to give alternate row colors to only the rows that have data-parent="" irrespective of the data that it has. "* this applies to all rows.

Answer (score 1):

This targets the "data-parent" alternatively. Code Updated

```css
table tr {
  background: #fff;
}
tbody tr[data-parent=""]{
  background: grey;
}
tbody tr[data-parent=""] ~ tr[data-parent=""]:nth-child(even){
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Week1</th>
        <th>Week2</th>
        <th>Week3</th>
        <th>Week4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-parent=""> //should be grey
        <td>+John(grey)</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hunohn</td>//ignore i.e white as background color
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hunohn</td>//ignore i.e white as background color
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent="">//yellow
        <td>+Boney(yellow)</td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent=""> //grey
        <td>+Dwihn(grey)</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent="">//yellow
        <td>+Arkon(yellow)</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>70</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent="6">
        <td>Tyulor</td>//ignore
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is close to what i need! but, I want alternate row colors only where data-parent="".please check here! https://jsfiddle.net/x6r8rq6a/10/

Comment: @AyushiZile change the rule to `even` and you're good https://jsfiddle.net/x6r8rq6a/11/

Comment: It wasn't exactly what i was looking for. but it helped a lot. Maybe i'll post another better worded question next time! thanks @blecaf

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tr[data-parent=""]:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
```

This will color every even `tr` with `data-parent=""` gray colored. Also, since its simple css, sorting will change the color accordingly.